"Introduction to Topological Manifolds" John Lee, Theorem 10.15
How do I know such a point $v$ below is guaranteed to exist? Wouldn't 3 closed disks side by side of radius 1, centered at (0,0), (2,0), and (4,0) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be a connected finite CW complex? What is the point $v$ in this example? My 2-cells would be each of the open disks, and each of their closures would just be the corresponding closed disk, correct? What $v$ exists in the closure of every 2-cell? I feel like I am misunderstanding something.


The comment immediately before the theorem says, "For technical reasons, the computations are much simpler if we assume that the base point lies in the closure of each of the $2$-cells. We leave it to the interested reader to work out the modifications needed when this is not the case." So such a $v$ need not always exist.


$v$ is not guaranteed to exist a priori, but every finite CW-complex is homotopy equivalent to one where such a point $v$ exists (contract a maximum spanning tree in the 1-skeleton, then all 2-cells whose closure doesn't meet the now-unique 0-cell). 2. Your counterexample is a counterexample. You aren't misunderstanding anything.


Okay, thank you. I misunderstood what that part of the text was saying.

If any moderators are reading this, my question is answered. If I have the ability to close the question right now, I do not know how.

You can mark the (new) answer as correct.

Combining the comments into an answer:
From @JohnPalmieri:
The comment immediately before the theorem says, "For technical reasons, the computations are much simpler if we assume that the base point lies in the closure of each of the 2-cells. We leave it to the interested reader to work out the modifications needed when this is not the case." So such a  need not always exist.
From @BenSteffan:

 is not guaranteed to exist a priori, but every finite CW-complex is homotopy equivalent to one where such a point  exists (contract a maximum spanning tree in the 1-skeleton, then all 2-cells whose closure doesn't meet the now-unique 0-cell).
Your counterexample is a counterexample. You aren't misunderstanding anything.

